# Error in location of NSMenu sing popUpContextMenu:withEvent

Tags: cocoa

The code is supposed to show a context menu when you click a button but when the menu appears it always appears way more to the right and higher then it should be, rather then at the position of the clicked button (or mouse since it's over the button at moment of clicking).

```
- (IBAction)menu:(id)sender {
    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:menu withEvent:[NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSLeftMouseUp location:[NSEvent mouseLocation] modifierFlags:0 timestamp:0 windowNumber:[_window windowNumber] context:nil eventNumber:0 clickCount:0 pressure:0] forView:menuView];
}
```

NOTE: the method was to long to fully put in the title

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[_window convertScreenToBase:[NSEvent mouseLocation]]`, not `[NSEvent mouseLocation]`